# mod_rewrite: Pass the path & query string URL as a parameter

Tags: regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite, parameters

I'm using mod_rewrite to rewrite pretty URLs to a form supported by a Spring 2.5 application.

```
e.g. /category/cat1?q=x   =>  /controller?category=cat1&q=x
```

However from my controller I want to know the original URL the request came from (so I can generate a link if required).  This approach is needed generically across all pages so it is difficult to hard code.

*How can I access the original path + query string from my controller?*

I have tried using $0 to include the full path but this doesn't include the query string.  I can't just append the path and the query string as this would result in some parts of the path being added as parameters `/category/cat1?category=cat1&q=x`  Note the addition of the unwanted `&category=cat1` parameter, this causes the URL to no longer match that sent from the browser.

I'm hoping mod_rewrite will let me reference the full URL and encode it as a parameter so my rule could look like:

```
RewriteRule /category/(.+)
            /controller?category=$1&_originalUrl=${escape:$0}?${escape:<original query string>}
            [QSA]
```

Using my original example the end result passed through to my controller would be:

```
/controller?category=cat1&_originalUrl=%2Fcategory%2Fcat1%3Fsearch%3Dx&search=x
```

The important part is the value of `&_originalUrl` which should be `%2Fcategory%2Fcat1%3Fsearch%3Dx` which in its unescaped version is `/category/cat1?q=x` (the original request URL that was sent from the browser).

Any suggestions welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: I've discovered an escape function ${escape:$1} at http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/ModRewrite Now I need to work out how to append the path and the original query string.

${escape:$0}${escape:<the original query string>}

Comment: Receiving the original path and query string in separate parameters would be a suitable solution. e.g. &_originalPath=${escape:$0}&_originalQueryString=${escape:<original query string>}  <original query string> is the part I don't know how to get.

Comment: Hi, got a similar problem to solve, but it seems the int:escape rewrite map won't do the trick : it's not url-encoding (like turning / into %2F, & to %26, etc), just encoding character not allowed in a url. Last option I can see is using an external mapping program, but it's just getting into more trouble... Or appending ";original_qs=<un-encoded qs>" to the rewritten url

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The query can ony be tested with [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) since [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) does only test the [URL path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax). See Jonathan Feinberg’s example how to do that.

But you could also just set the [*QSA* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) and the old query gets automatically appended to the new one:

```
RewriteRule ^/category/([^/]+)$ /controller?category=$1 [QSA]
```

---

**Edit**    In response to your comment to this question: If you want to get the initial requested URI path and query, you need to extract it from the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1) (*THE_REQUEST* variable):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ ([^\s]+)
RewriteRule ^/category/([^/]+)$ /controller?category=$1&_originalUrl=%1 [QSA]
```

But in most languages there is an environment variable with the very same information.

Comment: Thanks for the QSA example.  Sorry my example wasn't very accurate, I am using [QSA] to automatically appending the original query string to the rewritten URL.  What I'm trying to achieve is the get the original (unrewritten) path + query string as the user sees them in the browser, and pass that as an encoded parameter to my controller.

Comment: @richardpaul: In that case you should extract that information from the request line: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ ([^\s]+) RewriteRule ^/category/([^/]+)$ /controller?category=$1&_originalUrl=%1`

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture the query string in an initial, separate step.

```
RewriteCond %{query_string} ^q=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/category/(cat1)$ /controller?category=$1&q=%1
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks but I need to capture the entire query string, and it needs to be in a generic fashion (I don't know what parameters will be passed through).  I've updated the example to use QSA as per Gumbo's suggestion.

Comment: There's enough information in my answer to put you on the right road. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a host header you can use? Sorry for being so vague, but last time I had to do this was using PHP (urgh, dont ask), and I think thats how we did it - eg REQUEST_URI (http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html)

You also may be able to SET a host header in the rewrite (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

eg:

```
ReWriteRule /category/(cat1)?q=(x) /controller?category=$1&q=$2 [E=FOO:....]
```

(and no, I'm so totally NOT a mod-rewrite ninja)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was a bit vague in my original question.  I'm not concerned with the hostname, just the original path and query string.  I've updated the question accordingly.