# Mod_rewrite in .htaccess - forward anything that starts with index.php to ____

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

**UPDATE: This works:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ ([^\s]+)
RewriteRule (.+) /index.cfm?event=checkuri&uri=%1 [QSA]
```

---

**Some background...**

So we **already** have a catchall redirect in our .htaccess file which is this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) /index.cfm?event=checkuri&uri=$1
```

This ties into a database table that checks the URI for a match.  so if we just moved a site that used to have this page:

/some-awesome-article.html

Onto our system, and the new address is

/awesome-article/12442

and someone tried to access the old URI, our system would check for this, find a match, and forward them to the new home: /awesome-article/12442

---

This system works awesome, with one exception.  If the URI is something like /index.php?id=123412  then the whole system falls apart.  In fact /index.php/whatever won't work either.

Everything else works except for this.  We do not use PHP for our web application (although support says its in an admin console on the server somewhere).

---

So basically what I need is if index.php is detected anywhere it will forward the URI to our
existing system:

How can i modify this to fix it?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) /index.cfm?event=checkuri&uri=$1
```

Comment: Is the problem that you are trying to pass the original query string  (`id=123412` in your example) to index.cfm as additional parameters?

Comment: Mike I think you are close.  upon testing this IS working but they query string is not getting passed.


so index.php by itself actually worked.

But once you add on query string params it fails

So it would appear that all we need to do is change this:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) /index.cfm?event=checkuri&uri=$1

to ALSO pass along query params.  not sure how exactly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod\_rewrite: Pass the path & query string URL as a parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882694/mod-rewrite-pass-the-path-query-string-url-as-a-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting with mod_rewrite does not work on the full URL. In fact, the regex in the RewriteRule does only get the path and file, but not the query string. And so the backreference `$1` will only contain "index.php" and nothing else.

Additionally, the RewriteRule does change the query string because there is one in the target pattern. Because the flag `[QSA]` (query string append) is not present, the query string of the original request gets replaced instead of appended. So the query string is gone after this rewriting.

This would be a lot easier if you wouldn't mess with the query string. The easiest way of rewriting any url that is not an existing file would be if the second line would be simply `RewriteRule (.+) /index.cfm` - you could then get all info about the current request, including query string, path and file, in the script.

So now you'd have to fiddle with the query string. Adding `[QSA]` will pass the query string to your script and you'd have to detect what's inside. This will work only if you do not expect the query string to contain parameters named "event" and "uri" - these will be overwritten by your rewriting. If you need to add the original query string to the URL, it's a bit more complicated, because the string needs to be url-encoded.

[Here's how to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882694/mod-rewrite-pass-the-path-query-string-url-as-a-parameter)

Comment: This sounds close.  (the link). How would I change my rewrite rule syntax to pass along the WHOLE uri (encoded or not)

Comment: `%1` is a backreference to a regular expression in a RewriteCond, and `%{THE_REQUEST}` is the variable that contains the request.

Comment: Ok we're REALLY close:

This works:

     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !-f
     RewriteRule (.+) /index.cfm?event=checkuri&uri=$1 [L,QSA]

But any references to static content are now getting sucked into that.  So images and css files will not load.  How to fix...

Comment: There is a difference between THE_REQUEST and REQUEST_FILENAME. The latter is the filename on the filesystem, and the check in the RewriteCond is `!-f`, which is "if not a real file". If you change REQUEST_FILENAME to THE_REQUEST, this check will not find any real files anymore. Leave that in place. Add a RewriteCond that is always true after that which checks the whole string and allows to use it as `%1`.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your code to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) /index.cfm?event=checkuri&uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

QSA is for Query String Append that will make sure to append existing query parameters with the new ones.

Comment: Ok this is an improvement, the queryparams are not getting passed, but is there a way I can read them as a single string?

So for example, if the original URI was:


that gets forwarded here:
/index.cfm?event=checkuri&uri=/index.phpid=1234&color=blue&font=arial 

and I can not read the color, id, and font query params - but I do not know the original order.

Is there a way to somehow pass the whole thing?

Comment: Sorry your comment got truncated. What was the original URL that you want to pass as is?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you need to use the Query String Append `QSA` flag on your rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.cfm?event=checkuri&uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In your example case the rewrite would look like:

```
/index.cfm?event=checkuri&uri=index.php&id=123412
```

Comment: This ALMOST works except the changing of the ? to a & would fail our URI string checker

Comment: @JeffGladnick You would need to modify your URI string checker as the URI and the query string are two totally separate entities as far as Apache is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Sven was very close so I'm giving him the check

This ended up working perfectly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ ([^\s]+)
RewriteRule (.+) /index.cfm?event=checkuri&uri=%1 [QSA]
```