# htaccess mod rewriting url displays 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
#Create friendly URL
RewriteRule ^$1-$2.php?$3=$4$ (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/[L]
```

Hello again stackoverflow!

The current siteup of my site (let's call it site.com) has this setup:

http://site.com/category/page/variable1/value1/variable2/value2/
http://site.com/category/page/variable1/value1/
http://site.com/category/page/
http://site.com/

I want to rewrite those url's to:

http://site.com/category-page.php?variable1=value1&variable2=value2
http://site.com/category-page.php?variable1=value1
http://site.com/category-page.php
http://site.com/

The code above is the one I tried to write. It doesn't give me the Server error message, but instead just plainly doesn't work - When I go to http://site.com/category/page/variable1/value1/variable2/value2/, it just gives an 404 error.

Can you guys help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regex and replacement are switched in your RewriteRule. Also you present an example with six path segments, but your rule would only allow four. And did you check the examples in the http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info tag wiki yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882694/mod-rewrite-pass-the-path-query-string-url-as-a-parameter

Comment: @mario This was in case of the 2nd example of my setup, since I was just testing the initial rewriting.

Comment: @hungerstar Not that that answer is irrelevant since `category`, `page`, etc. have hundreds of different names and adding those manually to the .htaccess file is not handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got your regular expression and substitutions backwards. The snippet below just counts/captures the things between the slashes to do your rewrites.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /$1-$2.php?$3=$4&$5=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /$1-$2.php?$3=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1-$2.php [L]
```

Comment: I can't even acces my index.php file in the root directory anymore. How can I solve that?

Comment: Solved it, had to do with another htaccess file. Thank you kindly!