# Mapping URL routes to actions with Javascript in a SEO-friendly way

Tags: javascript, url, seo, url-routing

I've read about escaped fragments, but I don't think that it applies here because what I need to do is to route specific URL routes to certain actions on the same page **in a SEO-friendly way.**

Consider an example: a page has 30 posts in it. The markup is already there, no AJAX magic here. Once a user clicks a URL like `example.com/#/test-post`, I want to open a popup with the post contents (suppose that `test-post` is the post slug or any other content identifier).

This applies to posts, image galleries and pretty much any content that I want to show in a popup by matching a URL route to a certain Javascript action. The technical part is a piece of cake, but how would this perform SEO-wise? I understand that using separate pages for individual posts would probably be best, but is it possible to allow a single-page website to be crawled for individual posts so that the `test-post` accessed through `example.com/#/test-post` via Javascript ends up as a separate link in Google search results?

Answer (score 0):

Using Hash Properties in order to do different things on the same webpage via `JavaScript` might be really useful at some situations. However, looking it from a SEO prespective, I don't thing is a great solution at all.

The reason of that is that the fragment identifier introduced by a hash mark `#` is the optional last part of a URL for a document. It is typically used to identify a portion of that document. As a result from a SEO prespective, only one page will be stored.

I would suggest you, to make usage of `.htaccess` and `Friendly URLS` to do so. For instance, this might look like this:

```
SEO friendly URL: `www.example.com/test-post`

window.onLoad = function(){
   var URL = window.location.href;
   switch(URL){
     //Perfom different actions here
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, wouldn't `www.example.com/test-post` redirect my browser to a page that doesn't exist? I don't quite grasp the overall idea.

Comment: If you configure `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` propertly in order to do so, it won't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882694/mod-rewrite-pass-the-path-query-string-url-as-a-parameter @Onion